# Waiting for PowerPoint export to MP4 to complete

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using VBA to make a PowerPoint presentation save as an mp4 file. I want to close it when the save operation completes.

I do not know how to determine when this action is complete.

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs outFile, 39

Do  while  ????

ActivePresentation.close

Loop
```

The current solution I used is `wscript.sleep` but that not a good idea. because different powerpoint sizes take different amounts of time to do this

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs outFile, pptFormat

' save as MP4 need long time, do not close too early
If StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"MP4") = 0 then
    wscript.sleep 1000*60
End If
' Close the active document
ActivePresentation.Close
```

below is my using code

```
Option Explicit
 
'PPT2ANY "PATH_TO_INFILE\NEOHOPE.COM.IN.pptx","PATH_TO_INFILE\NEOHOPE.COM.OUT.pdf","PDF"
'PPT2ANY "PATH_TO_INFILE\NEOHOPE.COM.IN.pptx","PATH_TO_INFILE\NEOHOPE.COM.OUT.png","PNG"
PPT2ANY "D:\video\generateComplete1.pptx","D:\video\onlyVideo1","MP4"
'Call PPT2ANY(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1),WScript.Arguments(2))
 
Sub PPT2ANY( inFile, outFile, outFormat)
    Dim objFSO, objPPT, objPresentation, pptFormat
 
    Const ppSaveAsAddIn                             =8
    Const ppSaveAsBMP                               =19
    Const ppSaveAsDefault                           =11
    Const ppSaveAsEMF                               =23
    Const ppSaveAsExternalConverter                 =64000
    Const ppSaveAsGIF                               =16
    Const ppSaveAsJPG                               =17
    Const ppSaveAsMetaFile                          =15
    Const ppSaveAsMP4                               =39
    Const ppSaveAsOpenDocumentPresentation          =35
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLAddin                      =30
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLPicturePresentation        =36
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation               =24
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentationMacroEnabled   =25
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLShow                       =28
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLShowMacroEnabled           =29
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLTemplate                   =26
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled       =27
    Const ppSaveAsOpenXMLTheme                      =31
    Const ppSaveAsPDF                               =32
    Const ppSaveAsPNG                               =18
    Const ppSaveAsPresentation                      =1
    Const ppSaveAsRTF                               =6
    Const ppSaveAsShow                              =7
    Const ppSaveAsStrictOpenXMLPresentation         =38
    Const ppSaveAsTemplate                          =5
    Const ppSaveAsTIF                               =21
    Const ppSaveAsWMV                               =37
    Const ppSaveAsXMLPresentation                   =34
    Const ppSaveAsXPS                               =33
 
    ' Create a File System object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
 
    ' Create a PowerPoint object
    Set objPPT = CreateObject( "PowerPoint.Application" )
 
    With objPPT
        ' True: make PowerPoint visible; False: invisible
        .Visible = True
  
        ' Check if the PowerPoint document exists
        If not( objFSO.FileExists( inFile ) ) Then
            WScript.Echo "FILE OPEN ERROR: The file does not exist" & vbCrLf
            ' Close PowerPoint
            .Quit
            Exit Sub
        End If
  
        ' Open the PowerPoint document
        .Presentations.Open inFile
  
        ' Make the opened file the active document
        Set objPresentation = .ActivePresentation
  
        If StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"PDF") = 0 then
            pptFormat = ppSaveAsPDF 
        ElseIf StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"XPS") = 0 then
            pptFormat = ppSaveAsXPS
        ElseIf StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"BMP") = 0 then
            pptFormat= ppSaveAsBMP
        ElseIf StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"PNG") = 0 then
            pptFormat= ppSaveAsPNG
        ElseIf StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"JPG") = 0 then
            pptFormat= ppSaveAsJPG
        ElseIf StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"GIF") = 0 then
            pptFormat= ppSaveAsGIF
        ElseIf StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"XML") = 0 then
            pptFormat= ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation
        ElseIf StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"RTF") = 0 then
            pptFormat= ppSaveAsRTF
        ElseIf StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"MP4") = 0 then
            pptFormat= ppSaveAsMP4
        Else
            WScript.Echo "FILE FORTMART ERROR: Unknown file format" & vbCrLf
            ' Close PowerPoint
            .Quit
            Exit Sub
        End If
 
        ' Save in PDF/XPS format
        objPresentation.SaveAs outFile, pptFormat
        'objPresentation.CreateVideo  "D:\video\onlyVideo.mp4", false

        ' save as MP4 need long time, do not close too early
        If StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"MP4") = 0 then
            wscript.sleep 1000*50
        End If
        ' Close the active document
        objPresentation.Close
  
        ' Close PowerPoint
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Usually a call to an object method (`ActivePresentation.SaveAs`) will not return until it is completed. Are you sure you need to wait?

Comment: yes, if not wait, ppt will be close soon,  ActivePresentation.SaveAs doesn't seem to block the program

Comment: I am not sure it would work in your case, but from what I understood `DoEvents`  sort of forces the program to complete the task before passing to something else. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the way to solve my problem below

```
If StrComp(Ucase( outFormat ),"MP4") = 0 then
        wscript.sleep 1000*1
        outFilePath = outFile&".mp4"
        If objFSO.FileExists( outFilePath ) Then 
            Set f = objFSO.GetFile(outFilePath)            
            do until f.size > 0
                wscript.sleep 1000*1
            Loop
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.saveas) will return until it has completed saving the file. I would expect this code to work as you want:

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs outFile, ppSaveAsMP4
ActivePresentation.Close
```

Comment: I tried you code, but It didn't work the way I wanted it to, the ppt will close soon, and the mp4 file are not exported.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting to video spins off another process. SaveAs returns control to your VBA immediately but the video export's still taking place in a different process.

Shyam Pillai explains how to deal with this here:

http://skp.mvps.org/2010/ppt015.htm

The short explanation:  poll the presentation's CreateVideoStatus property in a loop until it returns a Done or Failed code.